# make disable , ui button random position swift

Tags: swift, xcode

there is a UIButton in view controller and when button clicked , UIButton move with random position in View Controller . **The question it is how i can make disable movable ability when clicked again on button ?**

this is moveable Method :

```
func randomPosition() {


    self.movable_Button.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    let buttonWidth = movable_Button.frame.width
    let buttonHeight = movable_Button.frame.height


    let viewWidth = movable_Button.superview!.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = movable_Button.superview!.bounds.height


    let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
    let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight

    let xPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
    let yPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

    movable_Button.center.x = xPosition + buttonWidth / 2
    movable_Button.center.y = yPosition + buttonHeight / 2

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have programmed something like

```
func onButtonClicked() {
   randomPosition()
}
```

so you can make a new variable:

```
var clickedButton = false

func onButtonClicked() { // i know this is not the correct function, but i think you know what i mean ;)
   if clickedButton == false {
       randomPosition()
   } else {
       clickedButton = true
   }
}
```